# c#, excel interop, copy worksheet, edit and save

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an excel workbook containing one spreadsheet. I want to open the workbook, copy the existing worksheet, edit some cells and save the copied worksheet to the workbook. I can access the sheet I want with the code below.

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(parsTemplatePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "par-template";
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
```

I have been unable to figure out how to save it to the workbook and start with a fresh unedited copy to edit/save (copy, edit copy, rename copy, add to workbook).

Update: Originally was setting copiedSheet to be equal to xlWorkSheet rather than using the copy method. Code below works for me as a good start

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Copy(missing, xlWorkSheet);
            var copiedSheetIndex = xlWorkSheet.Index + 1;
            Excel.Worksheet copiedSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.Item[copiedSheetIndex];
            copiedSheet.Name = "New Sheet - " + i;
            copiedSheet.Cells[4, "B"] = "Cell B4";
        }
```

Comment: What code have you tried?  Did you do a google search to find examples?  You can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Are you saying you want the copied worksheet to be stored in the same workbook - so it now has two worksheets, the first being the unchanged original, the second being the updated version. Or do you want to end up with two workbooks with a single worksheet in each ?